# Connect host to guest with VirtualBox on Host-Only-Network-Adapter

Tags: networking, virtualbox, debian, virtualbox-networking

I am using Ubuntu on VirtualBox as guest, on a Windows 7 host.

I would like to have this configuration: 
1) both guest and host connected to internet.
2) guest can reach host (through ping)
3) host can reach guest (through ping)

I setup a Host-Only-Network on the VirtualBox before importing the image of Debian, and then imported it, and everything worked fine with the internet. I got directly internet.

My Settings for the "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter" are the following:

> IPv4-Adress: 192.168.56.254
>
> IPv4-Subnetmask: 255.255.255.0

Here is the content of etc/network/interfaces:

> The loopback network interface
>
> auto lo
>
> iface lo inet loopback
>
> The primary network interface
>
> allow-hotplug eth0
>
> iface eth0 inet dhcp

The DHCP-Server is unchecked (disabled)

Now when I ping the windows host from the Debian guest, typing "ping 192.168.56.254" (I hope I am really pinging the guest here..) everything goes fine and the packets are sent back.

How can I ping the guest Debian from Windows now? Which address should I ping? How could I know and set the IP of the Guest Debian?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! As this question regards Debian, it's off topic here.

Comment: ok sorry! 
is it not the same? it should be the same issue for this specific subject.. something with the etc/network/interfaces ... i should add something there but i dont know what exactly

Comment: Please review http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask

Comment: Oww sorry! I've just seen I am using Ubuntu... o.O I will make an edit on the question

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly , basically this is the definition of host only. What problem are you having ?

Comment: Have you considered simply mounting a drive local to your  host in your guest configuration and moving data back and forth that way?

Comment: i am just trying to setup the virtual network now.. i can ping the windows host from my linux running on the virtualbox but i dont know how to setup the ip-adress of the linux host in the virtualbox.. i read somewhere that i should modify a file called interfaces but i dont know exactly how and what should i type in there

Comment: anyone could help? it will be really great if i get this tonight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution..

I added this part to this file: /etc/network/interfaces

```
# new network
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.56.101
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

then I had to enter this line on the Terminal:

> /etc/init.d/networking restart

and then I had to restard the virtual machine!